# Configure Ubuntu to always start with terminal & Xload open?

Tags: ubuntu, startup, window-management

Does anyone know how to configure Ubuntu 14.04 so that when it starts up I have a terminal window open (at my specified x,y coordinates and specified width and height), and the Xload application also loaded and running at a certain x,y location?

Comment: Are you using the default desktop environment?

Comment: Yes default environment.

Comment: You might get the idea from my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/586977/295286). Let me know if you want more info or details on this

Comment: @user411180 Apologizes for my tardy response, but i have been having some health issues. Answer posted, please review. Let me know if you like it and find it useful or anything requires fixing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preliminary notes:**

Before we even begin, you need to know the geometry of your screen. The following command achieves that part of the task:

`xprop -root | awk '$1~/NET_DESKTOP_GEOMETRY/ {print }'`.

Sample output from my dual screen set-up:

```
$ xprop -root | awk '$1~/NET_DESKTOP_GEOMETRY/ {print  }'                   
_NET_DESKTOP_GEOMETRY(CARDINAL) = 2390, 768
```

Next step would be to check out manual page for X server, i.e., `man x` , specifically GEOMETRY SPECIFICATIONS, according to which you can specify size and location on the screen in the following fassion `WIDTHxHEIGHT+XOFF+YOFF`, where XOFF and YOFF are offsets on the x-y plane of the screen.

There are two ways to tackle this task. The method number one is by specifying the geometry in the command that will run at start-up. The method number two is by using `wmctrl` tool in a script as show in my answer that I linked in the comments. Both achieve the task you want; first has advantage in avoiding installing additional software; second has advantage in using `wmctrl` that can be applied to a variety of tasks, for instance I used it for [launcher script](https://askubuntu.com/a/606072/295286) and [setting title for byobu](https://askubuntu.com/a/607084/295286).

**Method #1, native:**

Open startup applications menu (which can be accessed through searching in dash), and add new start-up application for `gnome-terminal` and `xload`. For `gnome-terminal` you will want to have something like this:

`Name` (call it whatever you want)

`gnome-terminal --geometry WIDTHxHEIGHT+XOFFSET+YOFFSET`

`Comment` (optional)

[image]

Similarly create one entry for `xload`, but the command would have to be slightly different:  `xload -geometry WIDTHxHEIGHT+XOFF+YOFF`

Also, notice that `gnome-terminal` sets width and height in columns and lines, while xload sets those in pixels. So in the screenshot above you see me create a startup entry for 30 colums (width) and 20 rows (height)

Here's two sample commands to start gnome-terminal in upper right of the screen and xload in lower right of the screen

`gnome-terminal --geometry 50x20+2390+0`

`xload -geometry 200x200+2390-0`

**Method #2, through use of wmctrl**

`wmctrl` is a very useful program for manipulating windows on screen through terminal. You can get it with `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`.

Next step, would be to write up a script that will do all the magic. Remember change the permissions on it to executable with `sudo chmod +x /path/to/script.sh`. Finally, create a `.desktop` file in your `.config/autostart` folder, which will actually launch the script upon your login. Refer [here](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/141247/295286) on how to write the `.desktop` file; or simply add path to your script as one of the startup items in startup applications window.

Perhaps a small advantage is that with `wmctrl` you don't have to guess  rows/columns ratio for the germinal; everything is done with pixels. The formula for `wmctrl` is `gravity, xoffset, yoffset,width,height` (don't ask what gravity of the window is, since I've no idea  myself, just use 0), and `-r` parameter implies "by reference" to a window with specific title

**The Script**

Notice, that for size and position parameters, I've simply recycled my old script with a few substitutions. I expect that you've read my previous notes on how `wmctrl` works and you should be able to substitute your own numbers. When in doubt, refer to `man wmctrl`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Author: Serg Kolo
# Date: 4/18/2015
# Description: A simple script open gnome-terminal and xload with 
#  specific size and position

sleep 1

gnome-terminal -t STARTING-WINDOW &
xload &

if [  $? -eq 0  ]

    then
        wmctrl -r STARTING-WINDOW -e 0,1300,300,250,250
        sleep 0.5
        wmctrl -r xload -e 0,1300,0,250,250
fi
```